# Jump particle effect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a question about making a particle for jumping, like a dust cloud when the player jumps, here is my player script:

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 5f;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;
    bool grounded = false;
    Animator anim;
    Rigidbody2D rgbd;

    void Start () {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
        rgbd = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }

    void Update () {
    }

    void FixedUpdate (){
        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (groundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);
        float movex = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (movex * speed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

        if (movex > 0){
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(1,transform.localScale.y);
        } else if (movex < 0){
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(-1,transform.localScale.y);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow)){
            if (grounded == true){
                rgbd.AddForce (new Vector2(0f, 4f),ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            } else {
                grounded = false;
            }
        }

        anim.SetFloat ("speed", Mathf.Abs (movex));
        anim.SetBool ("grounded", grounded);

        }
}
```

I want him to activate the particle system only once while in midair. I've tried a few things but when the player is in the air the particle system never stopped.

Comment: I want him to play the particle and just play one time, I don't know how to instantiate well too ):

Comment: You need to instantiate your particle whenever you want. These particle ojects should be destroyed when their duration is over. Check instantiate and onDestrot methods from Unity3d.

Answer (score 3):

What most people do is create a new copy of the particle system on every need and destroy it later.

So what you would need is a brand new particle system. Expand the **Emission** tab. In there set the **Rate** to 0 (0 particles per second). Below **Rate** there should be an empty list called **Bursts**. Add one burst. Set **Time** to 0.0 (should be set by default) and number of particles to whatever you need. That will shoot 1 burst of particles whenever the particle system runs. Note that if **Looping** is ON than the burst will happen on beginning of every loop.

So far so good. Now make a prefab from it (watch a tutorial if you need). Then, in your code declare a **Game Object** variable that will serve you as a particle system:

```
public GameObject jumpParticles;
```

back to Unity, feed your prefab into the Jump Particles slot in inspector. Now it's all ready to be copied and pasted wherever you need it. So create a method for this:

```
void SpawnJumpParticles(Vector3 pos){
    GameObject tmpParticles = (GameObject)Instantiate(jumpParticles, pos, Quaternion.identity); //look up how to use Instantiate, you'll need it a lot
    Destroy(tmpParticles, 3f);
}
```

this code will spawn particles and auto-destory them in 3 seconds. The **pos** argument in the function is where the particles will get created. All that's left is to call it from your code where you start the jump. I'll leave that to you :)) good luck.